# Game Development using C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am well in C# with WPF. Now i want to develop game using WPF. But the problem is i have no basic idea about game development. Can any one give me any advice or any web side or any book reference for game development.

Comment: What type of game?  Maybe you want to use XNA, which was made for indy game development: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [XNA Developer Centre](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the XNA game development studio. It is designed for building games on the PC and the XBOX. I you are only building a simple 2D game I would scrap C# and work in BlitzBasic or PureBasic as they are very easy to build games.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of games you want to write. If you want to write Puzzle games then WPF could work. Here is a nice tutorial that shows how to write a puzzle game in Silverlight: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WP7TrainingCourse_YourFirstWP7AppLab

If you want to write action games (Or pretty much any other kind of game) then XNA is the way to go like others have mentioned. It is a game framework after all.